# Retrieve URL for Action from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am calling a Controller Action from a view, within that controller I need to invoke another Action which I will invoke to save the view to a network location as either HTML or Image.

How do I retrieve the URL to an Action from within a Controller. Please note I need the actual URL, this means RedirectionToAction or View() wont work.

**Why?** I need to pass in a URL which will contain a call to a View. This view will be used to generate an image or HTML document using the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.

.NET 3.5; C#; MVC 1;

I could do something like this, but its dirty ... well it leaves me with that dirty feeling.

```
using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "MyWorkflowController", 
new {
   MyId = "bla",
   URLToGenerateImage = Url.Action("GenerateImage", "MyWorkflowController")   
}))
```

Comment: Some kind of hint to which platform (ASP.NET MVC (1/2/3), Rails, etc) you are using might be helpful.

Comment: What he said, some specifics on the language or framework, please!

Comment: Sorry guys, C#; .NET 3.5; MVC 1

Comment: Why can't you use View? Also are you actually calling another Action or just a method on the Controller class?

Comment: I need to pass in a URL which will contain a call to a View. This view will be used to generate an image or HTML document using the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.

@Lazarus if you have a better suggestion, I am all ears. Thank you for your participation!

Comment: Without understanding your objective for this it's tough to suggest an alternative, can you explain more of the why and what the final objective is, then I can possibly help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the MvcContrib.UI.BlockRenderer to convert to View to Html instead of generating the image. I proceeded to save the html string to a file system location.

Here is a link for further information

http://www.brightmix.com/blog/how-to-renderpartial-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

How about ContentResult - Represents a text result, so you could have

/Controller/GetUrl/id

```
Public ActionResult GetUrl(int id)
{  
   // builds url to view (Controller/Image/id || Controller/Html/id)
   var url = BuildImageUrl(id);
   return ContentResult(url);
}
```

in view you could have:

```
<a href="<% Html.RenderAction("GetUrl", "Controller", new { id = idSource } ); %>">GenerateImage</a>
```